# What is the difference of running a console app directly on the prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What is the difference of running a console app directly on the prompt

```
# myapp --arg=val1 --arg2=val2
```

as compared to running it through a shell script

./myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
myapp --arg=val1 --arg2=val2
```

What addition overhead is incurred through the scipt

It good to find out the shell will carry out the the process via fork and exec.

The task I was thinking about.
Say a xinetd request is to handle a request:

With a bash script being called to handle the request I could do some preprocessing like parsing varibales first then call the C app.
The C code will be less and it be more quicker to change variables value on the bash script first. Also I can break down tasks to multiple smaller c apps

If i called c directly to handle the request surely it will be faster and less resource but more coding.

Because bash option is easier but of course has the bash intermediate process.

I am thinking there could potential be lets say thousands of request so I want to know what the impact will be of the bash processes as intermediary glue

Comment: Why do you ask, and what motivates your question (so **why** are you asking)? Please **edit your question** to tell more.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Beyond initial overhead, the full cost really depends on what you're *doing* inside your shell script. If you have a bunch of cruft like `foo=$(grep -e something file | awk | awk)` -- performing process substitution and spinning up pipelines -- that's going to have considerably more overhead than starting the shell itself did. So we could tell you that overhead is only a small number of milliseconds, but then if your script isn't written efficiently that could potentially not be true at all.

Comment: (And then bash-as-`/bin/sh` and mksh-as-`/bin/sh` and ksh93-as-`/bin/sh` and dash-as-`/bin/sh` all have different performance costs -- you really should be measuring with your specific implementation on your specific hardware if you have any hope of getting a useful response).

Answer (score 0):

In practice there is no much difference (for the script you are showing).

Of course, there is the overhead (a few milliseconds) of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)-ing then [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)-ing (and both of them could fail in some rare conditions), and having your (new) shell interpret that script.

More importantly, any additional thing you do in the shell script (notably `cd`, `export`, `ulimit`, `exit` .... and other shell builtins) affects only that shell process.

Read also about the `source` builtin (which affects the shell doing it) and about `bash` functions.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead comes from reading the script file before executing the commands.

As a simple test, you could do something like:

```
strace myapp --arg=val1 --arg2=val2 2> strace_noscript.log
strace ./myscript.sh 2> strace_script.log
```

And look at the differences in system calls. You could also run `time` to get an idea on the actual time differences of running the app both ways, for example:

```
kom@thinky:~/c_practice/tmp$ time cat tmp.c > /dev/null

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
kom@thinky:~/c_practice/tmp$ time ./myscript.sh

real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Where `myscript.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat tmp.c > /dev/null
```

Comment: If optimizing this,  using `exec` to run the single command in the script would save a `fork()` call, improving performance somewhat.